# Any method of extending class won't return anything?

Tags: php, laravel

I have extended a class with my own, and if I hit method respondNotFound (which I am certainly hitting because i.e. dd() works if I write it in ApiController) it won't return anything. It just somehow skip return from respondNotFound and goes to this return below if statement with all null values for all data that are provided with json(what is actually a normal case, but this line should never be executed).

```
class LessonsController extends ApiController{

...some other methods here...

public function show($id)
{
    $lesson = Lesson::find($id);

    if (! $lesson) {
        $this->respondNotFound('Lesson does not exist');
    }

    return Response::json([
        'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transform($lesson),
    ], 200);

}
```

and the ApiController looks like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class ApiController extends Controller{

protected $statusCode = 404;

public function getStatusCode()
{
    return $this->statusCode;
}

public function setStatusCode($statusCode)
{
    $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
}

public function respondNotFound($message = 'Not Found')
{
    return Response::json([
        'error' => [
            'message' => $message,
            'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode()
            ]
            ]);
}}
```

I have also tried to call getter for statusCode in LessonController but same thing, it just does not reacting to return. But, as I mentioned above, If I die and dump anything in ApiController everything is OK, it works as it should, so if I dd this Response::json... I get it on the front.

Anyone had this issue yet, or any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: You need to put `return` in front of `$this->respondNotFound('Lesson does not exist');` in your `show()` method.

Comment: return is missing from if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem lies in the logic block. Try the following:

```
 if (!$lesson){
    return $this->respondNotFound('Lesson does not exist');
 }
```

You must stop the script with return keyword in the if block, else the script in the **LessonsController** will continue to run even after the **respondNotFound()** call.

Comment: Aahh...can't believe I've lost so much time on this :) Thank to all of you

Comment: It's alright, now you have learned something crucial :) Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add `return` before your `$this->respondNotFound('Lesson does not exist');` and all is going to work